# Is it possible to set up global rules in a Python script?

Tags: python

If we need to use some function multiple times within a script, can we define it globally as a rule? This rule would be applied to specific situations, for example:

When doing some calculations, we want all floats to be rounded off.
Instead of using the round() function every time:

```
def calc1():
    return round(val1)

def calc2():
    val2 = round(a+b)
    return round(2/3 + val2)
```

can we just declare globally within the script that we want all floats rounded and achieve the same result?

```
global_round()  # global rule that rounds off all floats

def calc1():
    return val1

def calc2():
    val2 = a + b
    return 2/3 + val2
```

Would there be any negative side effects of this approach?

Comment: if it also affects the libraries, they may not work properly anymore. What are you trying to achieve? Sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: This is probably achievable using decorators, or maybe overriding builtin class methods - but it smells funny. What is the actual issue underlying this question?

Comment: I am wondering whether this would lead to cleaner code. In this case, it seems to me that doing the operation on each object is redundant, so just setting it up once seems simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this effect by using **wrappers** and **decorators**.

Wrappers are a bit of a uncommonly used feature but can be very powerful when used in the right places. The way it works is that the wrapper is automatically called in place of your function and then calls your function from inside the wrapper function, which can do pre and/or post processing on your function (so it wraps your function). You invoke the wrapper by adding the wrappers name as a decorator before your function declaration.

In your case you would do something like this:

```
from functools import wraps
def RoundIt(func):
    """This wrapper rounds the output of the decorated function."""
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return round(func(*args, **kwargs))
    return wrapper


@RoundIt
def calc1():
    return val1

@RoundIt
def calc2():
    val2 = a + b
    return 2/3 + val2

calc1()

calc2()
```

Or if you want to be able to tell it the number of digits to round to, it gets a bit more convoluted, but you can pass a parameter like this:

```
from functools import wraps
def RoundIt(digits=0):
    """This wrapper rounds the output of the decorated function.
    Rounds the output to 'digits' number of digits.
    """
    def callable(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            return round(func(*args, **kwargs), digits)
        return wrapper
    return callable


@RoundIt(digits=2)
def calc1():
   ...
```

This is an example I sometimes use to time functions:

```
from functools import wraps
import time
def PrintTimeit(func):
    """This decorator prints the execution time for the decorated function."""
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        start = time.time()
        try:
            result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        finally:
            end = time.time()
            print("{} ran in {}s".format(func.__name__, round(end - start, 2)))
        return result
    return wrapper
```

Which is used like this (temporarily) on a function that I want to time for testing:

```
@PrintTimeit
def some_function(...):
    ...
```

You can find the docs and another example [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/FunctionWrappers)

Answer (score 0):

## TL;DR

You can, but you shouldn't.

## Explanation

Python is a dynamic language. So you could *override* the methods of the `float` type to do this. This is called [*monkey patching*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch).

But look at the methods of the float type:

```
>>> dir(float)
['__abs__', '__add__', '__bool__', '__class__',
 '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__divmod__', '__doc__',
 '__eq__', '__float__', '__floordiv__', '__format__',
 '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getformat__',
 '__getnewargs__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__',
 '__init_subclass__', '__int__', '__le__', '__lt__',
 '__mod__', '__mul__', '__ne__', '__neg__', '__new__',
 '__pos__', '__pow__', '__radd__', '__rdivmod__',
 '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__',
 '__rfloordiv__', '__rmod__', '__rmul__', '__round__',
 '__rpow__', '__rsub__', '__rtruediv__', '__set_format__',
 '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__sub__',
 '__subclasshook__', '__truediv__', '__trunc__',
 'as_integer_ratio', 'conjugate', 'fromhex', 'hex',
 'imag', 'is_integer', 'real']
```

You would have to override *all* of the double-underscore methods that do calculations to round their result.

First, that is a lot of work. Second, *this would significantly change the result of every calculation  done with `float`*. **Don't do this**!

If you want to use a fixed/floating point type with adjustable precision, use e.g. [`decimal.Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) from the standard library.